# why in PGAdmin, two statement only show one result

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

For example,

```
select 1;
select 2;
```

This will only show one result that is 2. But in Microsoft Database, you can show both results.

Comment: Because postgres only returns the results from the last executed statement.

Comment: @Bergi: it's not "Postgres", it's pgAdmin that does that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  It isn't just pgAdmin.  `psql -c` will do the same thing with a multi-statement string.  For the same reason, they both use libpq in the same way here.

Answer (score 0):

You can show both results in Postgres also. Using the psql client:

```
 select 1; select 2;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)

 ?column? 
----------
        2
```

So try on one line in pgAdmin. Some testing shows that pgAdmin does in fact convert the above to one line. The issue turns out to be further upstream. From [Query Editor and SELECT output in transaction](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/5310)(you will need Postgres community account to view):

> psycopg2 does not give output for multiple statements. The statements will be executed but only the output of last statement will be returned.

Which points at this [Supporting multistatement and UNION fetching #942](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/942). The explanation there is:

> While the wire protocol allows for it, libpq, used by psycopg to communicate with PostgreSQL, does not.

So the stack will not return all the statement outputs, just the last.

Comment: Thanks. now seems pgadmin4 not support it.